# Visual Studio and IIS Express randomly stops working

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2013, iis-express, devenv

I have been using this machine for development since a year and its a brand new one. Now from 2-3 days my visual studio stops working while I am running my asp.net MVC application and restarts. Sometimes IIS Express stops working and even the browser exits.

I have checked activitylog.xml

**Source: Editor or Editor Extension**

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Not enough storage
> is available to process this command at
> MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.RegisterClassEx(WNDCLASSEX_D wc_d) at
> MS.Win32.HwndWrapper..ctor(Int32 classStyle, Int32 style, Int32
> exStyle, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, String name,
> IntPtr parent, HwndWrapperHook[] hooks) at
> System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.Initialize(HwndSourceParameters
> parameters) at
> System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource..ctor(HwndSourceParameters
> parameters) at
> System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.PopupSecurityHelper.BuildWindow(Int32
> x, Int32 y, Visual placementTarget, Boolean transparent,
> HwndSourceHook hook, AutoResizedEventHandler handler) at
> System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.BuildWindow(Visual
> targetVisual) at
> System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.CreateWindow(Boolean
> asyncCall) at
> System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.OnIsOpenChanged(DependencyObject
> d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) at
> System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
> e) at
> System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
> e) at
> System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
> args) at
> System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex
> entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata,
> EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean
> coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue,
> OperationType operationType) at
> System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp,
> Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean
> coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue,
> OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal) at
> System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object
> value) at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.MouseTrackingQuickInfoPresenter.Render()
> at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.IntellisenseSessionStack.OnSessionPresenterChanged(Object
> sender, EventArgs e) at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.IntellisenseSession.RaisePresenterChanged()
> at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.QuickInfoSession.Recalculate()
> at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.QuickInfoSession.Start()
> at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.DefaultQuickInfoController.OnTextView_MouseHover(Object
> sender, MouseHoverEventArgs e) at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.WpfTextView.RaiseHoverEvents()

Some logs Before this error are as follows

- Begin package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Parallel]
- End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Parallel]
- Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
- Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
- Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
- Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
- Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
- Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
- Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
- Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
- Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
- Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
- Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
- Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
- Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
- Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib

Then error (pasted in the start) occurs.
Also where else should i look to trace the real cause as this is yesterday's log only.

### UPDATE

My event log actually gives devenv error

> Application: devenv.exe
>
> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>
> Description: The
> process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception    at
> MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.RegisterClassEx(WNDCLASSEX_D)    at
> MS.Win32.HwndWrapper..ctor(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32,
> Int32, System.String, IntPtr, MS.Win32.HwndWrapperHook[])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was (totally code related) due to RichTextBox control. Microsoft has given a work around for this bug [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/620588/system-componentmodel-win32exception-0x80004005-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command)